# Returning nth value from results or NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using the query

```
(select top (1) a.Description from ClientContactAttributes cca inner join Attributes a on a.AttributeId = cca.AttributeId where cca.ClientContactId = cc.ClientContactId order by cca.AttributeId desc) as Attribute1,
(select top (1) Description from (select top (2) a.Description, cca.AttributeId from ClientContactAttributes cca inner join Attributes a on a.AttributeId = cca.AttributeId where cca.ClientContactId = cc.ClientContactId order by cca.AttributeId desc) q order by q.AttributeId asc) as Attribute2,
(select top (1) Description from (select top (3) a.Description, cca.AttributeId from ClientContactAttributes cca inner join Attributes a on a.AttributeId = cca.AttributeId where cca.ClientContactId = cc.ClientContactId order by cca.AttributeId desc) q order by q.AttributeId asc) as Attribute3,
etc
```

to get a list of attributes added against a record. Currently it's returning the final result multiple times if **any** attributes have been added to that record, however ideally I'd want NULL to return if that attribute doesn't exist.

e.g instead of returning

```
Attribute1   Attribute2  Attribute3   Attribute4
Bed          Bath        Beyond       Beyond
Bed          Bed         Bed          Bed
```

I'd rather it returned

```
Attribute1   Attribute2  Attribute3   Attribute4
Bed          Bath        Beyond       NULL
Bed          NULL        NULL         NULL
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx). First assign each record a row number:

```
SELECT  cca.ClientContactId,
        a.Description,
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cca.ClientContactId 
                                        ORDER BY a.AttributeId)
FROM    ClientContactAttributes AS cca
        INNER JOIN Attributes AS a
            ON a.AttributeId = cca.AttributeId;
```

Then you can use this `RowNumber` column to [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) your data:

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  cca.ClientContactId,
            a.Description,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cca.ClientContactId 
                                            ORDER BY a.AttributeId)
    FROM    ClientContactAttributes AS cca
            INNER JOIN Attributes AS a
                ON a.AttributeId = cca.AttributeId
)
SELECT  pvt.ClientContactID,
        Attribute1 = pvt.[1],
        Attribute2 = pvt.[2],
        Attribute3 = pvt.[3],
        Attribute4 = pvt.[4]
FROM    Data
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(Description)
            FOR RowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
        ) AS pvt;
```

---

**EDIT**

If you don't understand then I have not answered properly! I am a firm believer in the proverb *"give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"*

If you have the following data in your two tables:

**Attributes**'

```
AttributeId | Description
------------+---------------
    1       |     Bed          
    2       |     Bath        
    3       |    Beyond
```

**ClientContactAttributes**

```
ClientContactID | AttributeId
----------------+---------------
       1        |    1
       1        |    2
       1        |    3
       2        |    1
```

Running the following:

```
SELECT  cca.ClientContactId,
        a.Description,
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cca.ClientContactId 
                                        ORDER BY a.AttributeId)
FROM    ClientContactAttributes AS cca
        INNER JOIN Attributes AS a
            ON a.AttributeId = cca.AttributeId;
```

Will give you:

```
ClientContactID | Description | RowNumber
----------------+-------------+-----------
       1        |     Bed     |     1
       1        |     Bath    |     2
       1        |    Beyond   |     3
       2        |     Bed     |     1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function simply assigns a unique number to each group (defined in the `PARTITION BY` clause), and this number is determined by the `ORDER BY` clause. so this line:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cca.ClientContactId ORDER BY a.AttributeId)
```

Is essentially saying, for each unique value of `cca.ClientContactId` I would like a unique number, starting at 1, where the lowest value of `attributeId` receives 1 and the number increments from there:

The PIVOT function, is much like an excel pivot table, where you want to convert the rows into columns. It has two fundamental parts, and I will work backwards here. The first part is the `FOR` clause:

```
FOR RowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
```

This is the values from the `RowNumber` column that you want to turn into rows. The column names will correspond to the values provided. The second part (first logically reading), defines the values that will go into these newly created columns. This has to be an aggregate function, and in this case it is:

```
MAX(Description)
```

Since you already know that `RowNumber` is unique for each `ClientContactId`, the aggregate function (which is required for PIVOT`) is actually meaningless, since there is only one value for description to aggregate.

Hopefully this makes a bit more sense.

Comment: That looks awesome, although I'm not going to pretend I full understand it yet! Just one typo - you've got a double ,, after a.description

Comment: That does make a lot more sense now thank you! (there is still one more ,, in the 2nd query by the way)
If I want to join more records to that, what is the most efficient way of doing it? Adding the joins in the initial query and then pivot that, or join them to the pivoted data?

Comment: It probably won't make much difference in terms of efficiency. SQL server tends to be very good at reorganising queries regardless of the order of sub queries and joins. If you are not sure, try both methods and compare the running times and execution plans