# SQL View to transpose data

Tags: sql-server, pivot, transpose

Hi wise people of the internet. I'm hoping someone out there can help me create a view that transposes some data.

Basically table of users and against each user is a lable. Each user can appear more than one record... and therefore more than one lable attached to them. Plus, I don't know what all the lables could be.

For example;

| USER | ROLE |
| --- | --- |
| CRAIG | ADMIN |
| DAVE | ADMIN |
| CRAIG | IT |
| DAVE | SALES |
| DAVE | DIRECTORS |
| DAVE | OPS |

Ideally I'd like my view to end with the data like

| USER | ROLE1 | ROLE2 | ROLE3 | ROLE4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CRAIG | ADMIN | IT |  |  |
| DAVE | ADMIN | SALES | DIRECTORS | OPS |

What label goes in which column isn't important to me at all.

Comment: How many can you have, maximum number of columns? Is it OK if we just have a fixed number of columns and `NULL` will go in any column where there are not that many?

Comment: Right now I have no idea how many the max would be. But yep simply putting null in the un-needed ones is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use Sql join left with 2 tables but table2 has many-to-one relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222228/how-to-use-sql-join-left-with-2-tables-but-table2-has-many-to-one-relation)

Comment: No not really as all of my data is in one table so there is no joining involved. :-( Also I don't know  all of the USERS in my example. These could vary day to day

Comment: The principle is the same, just without the join. Add a rownumber (you don't need `PARTITION BY` just `ORDER BY`), then pivot on the rownumber, here is another example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336589/returning-nth-value-from-results-or-null/26336823#26336823